# How to apply masonry to hidden div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using jquery **[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)** for grid layout.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">[...]</div>
    <div class="item">[...]</div>
    <div class="item">[...]</div>
    <div class="item">[...]</div>
    <div class="item">
        <select id="selectorColors">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="colors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">[...]</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 90
    });
</script>
```

But in my case I have some hidden div's that appears only when you select an option. Masonry works fine only for visible divs, but for hidden divs doesn't work, when I select an option the divs appears but overlapping.

```
$('select').change(function(){  
    if($('select').val() == '') {
        $('div.colors').hide();
    } else {
        $('div.colors').show();         
    }
});
```

I tried to reload items using the [`reload`](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#reloaditems) method as follow:

```
$('div.colors').show().masonry('reload');
```

But doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Docs say to use `.masonry('reloadItems')` not `.masonry('reload');`

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hiding the divs, try using `visibility:hidden` on them.
This way masonry should be able to take these divs into account on reload.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is pretty old but I had a similar problem where I wanted to load a masonry in a div that initially had display: none set. When I displayed the div the masonry wasn't shown correctly. I successfully reloaded the masonry with:

```
$('#masonry').masonry();
```

And all the tiles aligned correctly.